# Proving that for a smooth function if $f(\frac 1 k)=0 :\forall k\in \mathbb N$ then $f(x)=0 :\forall x\in[-1,1]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f\in C^{\infty} ([-1,1])$ and suppose there's a constant $M>0$ such that $|f^{(j)}(x)|\le M:\forall j\in\mathbb N$ (including zero) and for all $x\in [-1,1]$.
>
> Prove that if $f(\frac 1 k)=0 :\forall k\in \mathbb N$ then $f(x)=0 :\forall x\in [-1,1]$

I understand that the function is always smooth and Lipschitz, so it's always uniformly continuous too. So it can't be that $f(\frac 1 k)=0$ and for the closest irrational number say $y$ we will have $f(y)\neq0$ because that will contradict uniform continuity. It's a bit similar to Dirichlet function.

If I'm right then it can be proved without using the fact that the function is smooth and I should be able to find for $f^{(0)}$ a contradiction which should be enough but it doesn't feel right if I'm not using parts of the question. Also, I'm not sure on how to formally express the counter example, should i use the $\epsilon - \delta$ ? Heine with two sequences ?

Comment: I don't think this can be done. There are many smooth functions with compact support, what's to keep you from inserting one of these functions between $x=1/2$ and $x=1$?

Comment: @PA6OTA I don't know what compact support means but how can a function be uniformly continuous and have 'jumps' ?

Comment: What about $$ f(x) = e^{-1/x^2}\sin\frac{\pi}{x} $$ ?

Comment: Oh, I see. The derivatives are not bounded by the same constant. Ok.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio they are bound by the same $M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$R_n (x,0) =f(x)-\left( f(0) +\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{f^{(k)} (0) x^k}{k!} \right) ,$$
then we have $$|R_n (x,0)|\leq \frac{M}{(n+1)!}\longrightarrow 0$$   hence $f$ is analytic and therefore $f\equiv 0.$

Comment: The reminder is bounded by that because each derivative is bounded by $M$, I see.  I'm not familiar with analytic functions, does it mean that there's no error in the Taylor expansion ? Why does that means that $f=0$ ?

Comment: Yes, since $R_n (x,0)\to 0$ we have $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)} (0) x^k }{k!} $$ on $[-1,1]$ and hence $f$ is analytic. But zeros of analytic function $f\neq 0$ are isolated.

Comment: What do you mean by the zeros of an analytic function are isolated ?

Comment: Look here : https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Zeroes_of_Analytic_Function_are_Isolated