# Proving $f=0$ if $f({1\over k})=0$ $\forall k\in \Bbb{N}$ .

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion

Let $f\in C^{\infty}[-1,1]$ and let $M$ be a constant such that $|f^{(j)}(x)|\le M$ $\forall j\in \Bbb{Z}_{+}$ and $x\in [-1,1]$. Prove that if $f({1\over k})=0$ $\forall k\in \Bbb{N}$ then $f=0$.

I don't know what to do. I guess it has something to do with Taylor expansion and the remainder corollaries but I don't know it well enough to understand how to apply it in here. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking you want to prove $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$?

Comment: I guess. That is how the question was originally written...

Comment: The notation $C^\infty [-1,1]$ just means that $f$ has derivatives of all orders? Or does it mean that $f$ is real analytic? The latter property I would write $C^\omega$ or something, not $C^\infty$. (I ask because you mention Taylor expansion.) Addition: Oh, do you have a theorem that can be used to prove that $f$ is analytic from the bounds you have on its derivatives there?

Comment: The thing is, I don't know what analytic is :<
But I will check right now

Comment: In functions I mean

Comment: Perhaps, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818227/proving-that-for-a-smooth-function-if-f-frac-1-k-0-forall-k-in-mathbb-n-t).

Comment: I saw it, it ends up with the solver saying the function is analytic. I also checked the link she\he left but didn't understand how the fact that $f\equiv 0$ follows.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ first prove that $0 = f(0) = f^{'}(0) = ... $ it can be seen by continuity of $f , f ^{'} , ... $ then use $\textbf{Taylor aproximation theorem}$ so we have :
$$R(h) = f(x + h) - P(h)$$
where
$$P(h) = f(x) + f^{'}(x)h + ... + \frac{f^{r}(x)}{r!}h^{r}$$
and 
$$R(h) = \frac{f^{r+1}(\theta)}{(r+1)!}h^{r+1}$$
take $x = 0 $ and $|h|<1$ so we have $P(h) = 0$ and $ R(h) = f(h)$ since $f^{r}(x)$ is bounded and r is arbitrary we can use the fact $\lim{r \to \infty}R(h) = 0$ because $|h| < 1$   so :
$$f(h) =0 $$
for $h \in (-1,1)$ and since $f$ is a continuous $f(1) = f(-1) = 0$